# Three Columns Using Divs

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with using Divs and CSS instead of tables and I am having some problems with my code/CSS. I am trying to set this up so I have 3 columns next to eachother in a container that is centered to the page which has the text aligned to the bottom so the text is around the same height as the bottom of the image I am using in the center column. I have been unable to achieve this and I have a new found respect for UI guys. My code and CSS are as follows. Any guidance would be helpful :)

```
           body {
        }
        #Container
        {
        border:1px solid #dddddd;
        padding:40px 94px 40px 94px; 
        background:#ffffff;
        width:55%;
        height:auto;
        border-radius:0px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        position:relative;
        }
        #Address
        {
        border:1px solid #dddddd;
        position:relative;
        text-align:left;
        width: 33%;
        }
        #Phone
        {
        border:1px solid #000000;
        position:relative;
        text-align:right;
        width: 33%;
        }
        #Logo
        {
        border:1px solid #4cff00;
        position:relative;
       float: left;
        width: 33%;
        }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="Container">
        <div id="Address">123 Testing Street</div>
        <div id="Phone">(ccc) 223-3323</div>
        <div id="Logo"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0c/ITunes_11_Logo.png" /></div>
    </div></blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLZu2/1/) , This is not 100% everything you asked for, but it is a big start!  You have the appearance of a table while only using div's.  I am not going to finish every little detail for you, but this should get you going, it is almost complete.

```
#Container{
   border:1px solid #dddddd;
   padding:5px; 
   background:#bbb;
   width:55%;
   margin: 0px auto;
   position:relative;
   height:200px;
        }
.cell{
   display:inline-block;
   width:32%;
   height:100%;
   border:1px solid #000;
   position:relative;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   line-height:370px;}

 <div id="Container">
    <div id="Address" class="cell">123 Testing Street</div>
    <div id="Phone"  class="cell">(ccc) 223-3323</div>
    <div id="Logo"  class="cell">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0c/ITunes_11_Logo.png" style="height:50px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was a huge help and I was able to manipulate it fairly easily. What was my big problem? I need to learn more about the display attribute.

Comment: you needed either display:inline-block, or in the other example Sam uses float:right;    you need one of the two to get div's to line up horizontally

Comment: Also you should never have 3 div's with unique id's and they all have identical properties.  What you do is give them all the same class and only type it once

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your css a bit. See if this is what you're looking for.

```
#Container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    background:gray;
}
#Address, #Phone, #Logo{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    height:256px;
    line-height:512px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39M9L/1/

Part of the problem you're going to have with aligning to the image is there is white space around the logo, so to get the text to align to the edge of the logo, you're going to have to tweak the numbers a bit, rather than rely on the image height.

Comment: When u use line-height like that, u can't set border to your div! Otherwise, the text will be in the middle of your div.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, i didn't think that we could add the height of the div

Answer (score 0):

You can add a span within a div, and use margin-top to make it in the bottom of the div.

CSS:

```
#Container > div {    
    min-height: 52px;
    float: left;       
    text-align: center;
}
#Container > div > span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 35px;
```

}

Take a look: [JSFIDDLE] (http://jsfiddle.net/blck/txXE2/)